# Bandwidth of CRC32 (or alternative hashing algorithms)

Tags: performance, bandwidth, crc32

How fast can one compute CRC32 for hashing very large amounts of data? (order of magnitude GB per second)

What about MD5?

Other, faster hashing algorithms like adler32?

Does anybody have real-world speed test results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like [this table](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html)?